# how to retrieve dynamic scripts from javascript

Tags: javascript

In my project i have to retrieve the content in all script tags. I am able to do this by simply including

```
var scrpt=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
script_txt=scrpt[i].innerHTML;
```

but by using the above code i am not getting dynamic scripts which are created by

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.src="http://somefile.js";
```

not only this there are many other ways of creating dynamic scripts like

```
document.write('<script src="">');
```

and

```
document.body.innerHTML='<script src="">';
```

and many more. I tried to retrieve it by using regular expressions like this

```
var pattern=/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.].*?)=(document.createElement\((.*)\));
/g;
```

but this may not match all.

Can anyone suggest a better method for achieving this property.

Comment: i even tried this but this does not yield the dynamic script created

Comment: The main issue here is WHEN are you running the function to retrieve the scripts. There are scripts that will be fetch only after the user is clicking (e.g. Ads). So you want to make sure the triggers to your 'collecting' function is done after such events as well.

Comment: Do not use the innerHTML property, since script content isn't markup. Use the [text](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-81598695) property.

Comment: @dbaseman—`document.scripts` is an HTML5 feature and therefore not suitable on the general web since many browsers don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

The first method you mentioned, using `document.getElementsByTagName('script')`, is fine.

I wrote up a fiddle where I'm counting script tags before and after inserting a tag dynamically. It works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/crGx9/

Could you show us an example of when it doesn't work?

Comment: This works fine for your page. but imagine if you are counting scripts in other webpage for suppose you are extracting scripts from google.com by using userscripts then how can this be done

Comment: Have you made sure that you're not running inside an iframe for example? `document.getElementsByTagName` will only get tags from the same frame you're executing in.